# Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable RDP to a Server 2008 R2 on another network? VM network](https://superuser.com/questions/513678/how-to-enable-rdp-to-a-server-2008-r2-on-another-network-vm-network)

On my computer, I can't seem to connect to a remote server via RDP. However, a colleague was able to connect to it on a computer on a different network connection, so its not a problem at the server end. To check if it's a problem with the network, here's what's been done:

- Firewall is disabled
- Tried typing the computer name, as well as ip
  address on RDP.
- Tried to connect via three different networks on same computer,
  wireless and wired.

So it seems that the problem is not with the network, but with my computer itself. Are there any other settings that i need to change on my computer in order to enable the Remote access?

I'm using windows 7 32-bit. And I have administrator privileges.

Comment: can you ping the remote server?

Comment: @Robotnik - no i can't